# Reputation of converted answers

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, behavior

As you can see, I don't have much reputation and to be helpful, sometimes you have to ask questions or just want to add something to another answer as comment. Now, I just started on a new subdomain on stackexchange and had something to add to an answer. I got several upvotes and finally I was able to comment and vote and this stuff you can do with your first couple of hundred points. Then, a moderator or someone like that converted my answer into a comment and all the upvotes with the including reputation and privileges are gone...

Wouldn't it be less frustrating if you would at least still have your privileges to comment? How should I proceed now? Now, I have to answer again instead of comment. In my opinion, this is destructive.

Comment: Sure it can be frustrating.  Likewise, wouldn't it be less frustrating when SO users can be shielded from the unlimited comments of a user that has trouble making useful contributions?  Spock: “Logic clearly dictates that the needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few.”  Kirk: “Or the one.”  Keep at it, you'll get there.

Comment: Isn't it more frustrating that your answer got converted into a comment and you don't understand why? You don't seem to really care about that, but it is actually the trigger and key to this whole situation.

Comment: I understand why, it is because I said in the answer that I would like to have it as comment but don't have the privileges for that.

Comment: Okay. So basically you ignored the site's rules and posted a comment as an answer, and now you think you still deserve to keep the reputation and privileges that came with that act. I'm going to leave it at that.

Comment: Lemme get this straight. You post what you KNOW isn't, and shouldn't be, an answer.... But you want rep for it? That's new. If you want the rep to comment... Post real answers. Or do a couple of edits. Maybe ask a good question or two. Lots of options. Posting comments as answers and hoping to keep the rep from misusing the system doesn't make sense

Comment: I don't care for rep, I just want to keep my comment privilege. I usually do not post answers because I know that there is somebody who has a better one. And as you can see, you're not the only one saying this and I got my answer.

Comment: @Greaka rep = your commenting privilege. So you kinda care for rep. To get comments, you need rep. To get rep, you need to use the site the way it was intended. simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you're lucky.

See, answers should be answers. If your message was not worth an answer, it shouldn't have brought you reputation points. But indeed it might be worth a good comment. The upvotes show that some users agreed and supported your opinion.

Most answers that are not answers just get deleted from the review queue. But yours was converted into a comment. This way the valuable message in it was preserved and put in the right place. Isn't that better?

As for inability to post comments before 50 rep: it is required to block spam, offence and all kinds of noise. It is also applied to users with good intents because telepathy-over-internet is not yet invented.